# Error Migrating from Orient DB 1.1 to 2.2

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

We are currently using orient db 1.x which supports local storage. Now since it is deprecated we have decide to move to orient db 2.2 and move the database to plocal storage. I am using below steps to migrate the db:

Export the database in Orient DB 1.1

1. Run console.bat
2. connect local:../databases/mydb admin admin
3. export database mydb.export

Import the database in Orient DB 2.2

1. Run console.bat
2. create database plocal:../databases/mydb admin admin
3. import database mydb.export ( I have tried all possible permutations of different option of Orient DB)
4. After this step I get this error: "OIndexException: index with name dictionary already exists"
5. To resolve this I tried dropping the index using this command: drop index dictionary
6. I have again tried to import using this command: import database mydb.export . This time the import is successful.
7. I then disconnected and exited from the orient db console.
   Now the problem is whenever I am trying to connect to this db using orient db console or GUI, I get below error:
   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage ..databases/mydb' with mode=rw
   java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 23

For resolving this, I have gone through many tutorials here and there. But I cannot resolve it. Any leads from anyone on this issue would certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

You should try upgrading it step by step, starting from 1.3.x
See [Compatibility Matrix](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Upgrade.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question have same steps that are there in the link you shared.

Comment: Try to update to the 1.3 first, than 1.4 ecc, only than go for 2.x